# > Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I have been trying to resolve errors while implementing flutter_google_map and everytime I do so, I get a new build error. In the beginning, I had the minSdkVersion error. After I resolved it I got another error in flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle, while trying to resolve this, I am getting another error

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

here's my android/build.gradle file:
`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }


    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.test_app1"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

flutter {
source '../..'
}

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `'com.google.gms:google-services:X.Y.Z'` dependency to your root-level build.gradle? If not, I don't think app-level build.gradle will be able to resolve that plugin.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        //Insert the latest version to X.Y.Z
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:X.Y.Z'
    }
}
```

Comment: hi. Thankyou for your help. I added the dependency and now I am getting another error      * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not open cp_proj generic class cache for build file 'C:\Users\Nada\AndroidStudioProjects\test_app1\android\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Nada\.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\df84n0lg5ce2v3xe6oz6p8kob).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

Comment: In path: ```android/gradle/wrapper/```  can you open ```gradle-wrapper.properties``` and edit your ```distributionUrl``` to support the latest gradle version: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip (this is my latest one, update it according to your Java version and latest gradle version).